# How to validate multiple email in laravel validation?

Tags: php, validation, email, laravel, laravel-validation

I have done all the things for the validation for the variable in laravel but for emails I got one simple problem.

From doc of Laravel,

```
'email' => 'required|email'
```

I got to know this is for only one email address but for like,

```
email=abc@xyz.com,xyz@abc.com, def@ghi,com
```

When I send array of the email i still get email is not a valid email.
I have done more like,

```
'email' => 'required|email|array'
```

But I still got error. can any body help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to write custom Validator, which will take the array and validate each ofthe emails in array manually. In Laravel 5 Request you can do something like that

```
public function __construct() {
    Validator::extend("emails", function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
        foreach ($value as $email) {
            $data = [
                'email' => $email
            ];
            $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}

public function rules() {
    return [
        'email' => 'required|emails'
    ];
}
```

Comment: To extend this answer, remember to add the custom validation message on your validation.php language file.

Comment: Also, [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#using-extensions) suggest putting this in `\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::boot`

Comment: As of Laravel 5.6 you don't need to do this. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271104/255260

Answer (score 13):

In 5.6 or above you can define your validator rule as follows:

`'email.*' => 'required|email'`

This will expect the `email` key to be an array of valid email addresses.

Answer (score 11):

We can achieve this without custom validation,We can overridden a method `prepareForValidation`

```
protected function prepareForValidation() 
{
   //Here email we are reciving as comma seperated so we make it array
   $this->merge(['email' => explode(',', rtrim($this->email, ','))]);
}
```

Then above function will call automatically and convert email-ids to array, after that use array validation rule

```
public function rules()
 {
     return [
        'email.*' => 'required|email'
     ];
 }
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I had to wrap the `explode` call in `array_filter` to avoid passing a single-value array with an empty string. Also, this is giving me some trouble with displaying validation messages, since it's now failing on e.g. `foobar.0` instead of just `foobar`.

Comment: You can use public function messages() for format messages like 'foobar.*.required' => 'email format is wrong'. Then foobar.0 will not come

Comment: This is better and more "Laravel-like". `$this->merge(['email' => array_map('trim', explode(',', $this->email))]);`

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.2 introduced array validation and you can easily validate array of emails :)

All you need is exploding the string to array.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: Only relevant if there are multiple inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this. Working good for me.
if email or emails (email1@gmail.com, email2@yahoo.com, email3@gmail.com) are coming from a Form like this following custom validator works. This need to be added to - AppServiceProvider.php - file. And new rule is - 'emails'.

```
    /**
     * emails
     * Note: this validates multiple emails in coma separated string.
     */
    Validator::extend('emails', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $emails = explode(",", $value);
        foreach ($emails as $k => $v) {
            if (isset($v) && $v !== "") {
                $temp_email = trim($v);
                if (!filter_var($temp_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }, 'Error message - email is not in right format');
```

And in your controller, it can be used like this:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email_txt_area' => 'emails',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to override `prepareForValidation` just because of one rule here's another approach using closures:

```php
$rules = [
    'name'  => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $emails = array_map('trim', explode(',', $value));
            $validator = Validator::make(['emails' => $emails], ['emails.*' => 'required|email']);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $fail('All email addresses must be valid.');
            }
        },
    ],
];
```

Tested with Laravel 9.x