# Validate multiple emails in a single text field using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

How can I validate that multiple is correct in a text field using Laravel?

Example 1:

The 3 emails are fine, therefore it **return true**

[image]

Example 2:

The first 2 emails are fine, but 3 is incorrect **return false**

[image]

For now, only the code that validates a single email

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
      'emails' => 'required|email'
   ];
}
```

Thanks.

PS: The number of emails can vary (1 to N)

Comment: Writing a custom validator that explodes and checks is of course an option. I don't think it's possible using existing rules in the framework, maybe someone else does.

Comment: Look at the "After Validation Hook" section at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

Comment: I cannot believe that anonymous function callbacks are not supported, or at least if they are then their documentation is hidden quite well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex validation in this case :

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
      'emails' => ['required','regex:/^(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+)$/g']
   ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend a new validator called "emails" that explodes your value and validate each email separately.

A fine solution can be find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29455516/405217

Answer (score 0):

How are you posting the request?

If you are using javascript/ajax you can split the email field before sending and put it into three different fields like email[].

Then in your controller you can do something like

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email.*' => 'required|email',
    ],[
        'email.*.email' => 'In case you are wondering how to set error messages for this kind of validation'
    ]);
```

If you are not using Javascript, you may consider using more than one field or writing some custom validation as suggested by @TobiasK

Comment: Finally I ended up using the code of this gist. It works perfectly to validate emails and other types of multiple data in a single input (dates for example). Cheerz.

https://gist.github.com/snipe/24aca75a3cdcd6b73932